# How add my application content with description and preview to Google search results?

Tags: android, google-search, android-search, google-app-indexing

I found this article: [A new way to search for content in your apps](https://search.googleblog.com/2016/08/a-new-way-to-search-for-content-in-your.html) and I'm really excited for this opportunity. I want to show my application content in google search results, like this:

[image: Google In Apps Search]

But this article doesn't have any information about how to implement this features in your app.

I use **App Indexing API** in my application, as described in articles:

- [Add the App Indexing
  API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/activity)
- [Add URL and App Indexing
  Support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html)

This is my code:

```
...
  private GoogleApiClient mClient;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ac_main);
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
  }

  public Action getAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
        .setName("Test Content")
        .setDescription("Test Description")
        .setUrl(Uri.parse("myapp://com.example/"))
        .build();

    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW).setObject(object)
        .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mClient.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mClient, getAction());
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mClient, getAction());
    mClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
  }
...
```

And this is result:

[image: Search result]

Google show my application's *Test Content* but without description and preview image. **Is there any ways to add description and preview image in Google Search Results?** (like Youtube or Twitter)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
     Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
    .setName("Test Content")
    .setDescription("Test Description")
    .setUrl(Uri.parse("myapp://com.example/"))
  //.put("image","YourImageUrlHere")
  //I took one android logo url
    .put("image","http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Android_Logo_04.png")
    .build();
```

That Image can be ImageObject or a Image Url.

You are using Action.VIEW_TYPE.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/Action#TYPE_VIEW

As per the documentation,

public static final String TYPE_VIEW

The act of consuming static visual content.
Constant Value: "https://schema.org/ViewAction"

Refer https://schema.org/ViewAction you can find "image" object under "Properties from Thing".

Hope it will help you.